# Would this cause a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

The closure captures self.

```
class SubmissionViewController: UIViewController {

    private let submision = Submission()

    private func removePerformances(_ performances: [Performance]) {
        performances.forEach {
            self.submission.remove($0)
        }
    }

}
```

`Performance` is a class.

`[Performance]` is a value type though, right ? So if it's a value type then it's passed in as a copy. So no worries I guess ?

Confused...

Edit: Any given instance of performance does not reference SubmissionViewController

Comment: do instances of `Performance` keep any reference of `SubmissionViewController` or its properties?

Comment: no they don't @holex

Comment: No, there won't be any retain cycle here. forEach() function doesn't store your closure. So it will enumerate all items in an array, then closure will be deallocated.

Comment: In terms of best practice, would it be best to code cautiously and set weak or unowned ? In theory, the forEach function could change and store the closure someday, maybe by accident.